# Tkinter defaulting to all radiobuttons being selected, despite value being set

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter

The following code gives weird results. Despite having a value set for every one, they all default to selected. Outside of a class, this code (minus the self call) works perfectly.

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import *

class fire():
    def __init__(self, root):

        self.var = IntVar()
        self.var.set(2)
        r1 = Radiobutton(root, text="1",variable=self.var, value=1)
        r1.pack()
        r2 = Radiobutton(root, text="2", variable=self.var, value=2)
        r2.pack()
        r3 = Radiobutton(root, text="2", variable=self.var, value=3)
        r3.pack()


root = Tk()
root.geometry("50x175")

fire(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Doing some reading online, there's no reason this shouldn't work, right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to save a reference to the instance of `fire`:

```
f = fire(root)
```

Without the reference, the python garbage collected will destroy the variables.

Comment: Yeah that'll do it. Can't believe I missed that. Much appreciated!